# Converting string to MySQL timestamp format in php

Tags: php, android, mysql, string, timestamp

I am writing a query in php using a string sent from a android java application.

 The query is something like :

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO app_DuckTag (taste) VALUES (%s) WHERE species=%s AND timestamp=%s",
                         GetSQLValueString($_POST['taste'], "text"),
                         GetSQLValueString($_POST['species'], "text"),
                         GetSQLValueString($_POST['timestamp'], "text"));
```

But I doubt timestamp is stored as a string inside MySQL. 

 How should I convert the string to time format as in MySQL? 

 The strtotime(string) php function converts it to unix time. 

But the MySQL stores it differently, I guess. Thank you.

EDIT: This is how it shows up in MySQL phpmyadmin: 2011-08-16 17:10:45

EDIT: My query is wrong though. Cannon use a where clause with Insert into. 
The query has to be UPDATE .... SET ... = ... WHERE .... 
But the accepted answer is the correct way to use the time inside the WHERE clause.

Comment: How are you receiving it from the android application?

Comment: $_POST['timestamp'] = "2011-08-16 17:10:45". Hope this helps. If not please ask me and I'll post it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This should be all:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_POST['timestamp']));
```

if you want to check for timezones and such you should use strftime instead of date

Answer (score 3):

If you can get the input 'string' (which you haven't provided the format that you're receiving it in) to a Unix timestamp value, you can easily convert it to a MySQL datetime format like this:

```
$mysqldatetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unixTimeStampValue);
```

This will produce a **string** similar to the following:

> 2011-08-18 16:31:32

Which is the format of the MySQL *datetime* format.  If you are using a different time format, then the first argument to the `date` function will be different.

See the manual for the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function for more information and other ways you can format the value that it returns.

**Edit**

You are receiving a string formatted in MySQL datetime format.  After sanitizing it, you can insert it directly into the database.  To MySQL it may be a 'datetime' data type, but to PHP it is simply a string (just like your entire SQL query is nothing more than a string to PHP).

```
$timestamp = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['timestamp']);
```

You should be able to safely insert that into your database for the timestamp field.

Comment: I receive it in exact same way but as a string - "2011-08-16 17:10:45"

Comment: Will check and let you know. I guess if I can insert it into a timestamp field then I must be able to check if its the same in a WHERE clause too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) in mysql. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Because I do not have the time in UNIX format. I have it exactly like I want but as a string. I have accepted an answer that works.