# Converting a string timestamp to a MySQL timestamp with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting string to MySQL timestamp format in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112982/converting-string-to-mysql-timestamp-format-in-php)

Given a date in the following format, how would I convert it into a MySQL `TIMESTAMP` format in PHP?

```
Tue, 06 Dec 2011 16:47:11 +0000
```

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7112982/4418), but am having some difficulty in converting it into what I need.

Comment: @hakre - I referenced that question above already; this is a related, but different, question

Comment: @hakre - I accepted the answer because it explained what I needed. As already stated, it is different (though similar, and I never said "oh but so different" - please do not put words in my mouth I neither said nor intended).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('Tue, 06 Dec 2011 16:47:11 +0000'))`

that's 'canonical' form, but MySQL will also accept

`date('YmdHis',strtotime('Tue, 06 Dec 2011 16:47:11 +0000'))`

(more details about that format: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html )

Comment: thanks - there's the conversion I needed :) .. I thought `strtotime` needed the 'now()' call, or another time to use as a base

Comment: +1 because I never knew MySQL would accept `YmdHis` instead of `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

Comment: @drrcknlsn: take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html then for some more interesting stuff