# Save PHP date string into MySQL database as timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, date, format, timestamp

I am trying to save a datestring in PHP into a MySQL database as timestamp datatype. I found a lot of posts about this, but none of them worked for me. This is what I've tried:

```
$date =  $_POST['date'];
$timestamp = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($date));
$sql = "insert into sale(service, amount, date, customerid_fk) values('$service', '$amount', '$timestamp', '$id');";
```

But in the database, I only get:

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

The input string from the POST object is `05/30/2013`. Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: mySQL expects the `Y-m-d` format for timestamps. Change the format string accordingly and you'll be good.

Comment: Did you already check this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501915/convert-date-string-to-mysql-datetime-field

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112982/converting-string-to-mysql-timestamp-format-in-php is what you need i expect.

Comment: If you want to pass the parameter as a string then convert it into the DB use STR_TO_DATE(yourstring, '%m/%d/%Y')

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
$date =  $_POST['date'];
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));  

 $sql = "insert into sale(service, amount, date, customerid_fk) values('$service', '$amount', '$timestamp', '$id');";
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
//timestamp fix
$date = new \DateTime();
$created_at = $date->setTimestamp(intval($timestamp));
```

Answer (score 1):

We have `NOW()` function in **MySQL**.

```
insert into sale(service, amount, date, customerid_fk)values('$service', '$amount', NOW(), '$id');
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove apex for put timestamp as long

```
insert into sale(service, amount, date, customerid_fk) values('$service', '$amount', $timestamp, '$id')
```

or use this format for date 'Y-m-d H:i:s'

Answer (score 0):

if you have date field type as `DATE` or `DATE/TIME` it will add timestamps like this. you need to make your date field type as varchar and add your timestamps as strings.

if you need to add date in format d/m/y then mysql has different format like `y-m-d` so before adding you can do like this

`date('y-m-d', strtotime('your-date-string'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2005-03-27 03:00:00');  -- **1111885200**
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1111885200);              -- **2005-03-27 03:00:00**
```

```
$date =  $_POST['date'];
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));  

$sql = "insert into sale(service, amount, date, customerid_fk) values
    ('$service', '$amount', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$timestamp'), '$id');"
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use mysql methods

I got this date from a datebox  of easyui

08/25/2016

then

```
$date = "FROM_UNIXTIME(".strtotime(08/25/2016).")";

INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2, dateI) values($a, $X, $date);
```